# Excel: single cell to multiple rows and get substring

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file, it contains following data in single cell and I need to separate it in multiple rows on the basis of new line and then detect the first 22 characters and next 15 characters (25th to 40th) of every row cell. You would have a line like this:

```
         Dec 2, 2014, 11:23 PM - ‪+91 90000 80000: loren ipsum 
         Dec 2, 2014, 11:24 PM - +91 90000 80000: loren
```

and desired output will be

```
          Dec 2, 2014, 11:23 PM
          Dec 2, 2014, 11:24 PM
```

and

```
          loren ipsum 
          loren
```

Comment: Too lazy to write the whole formula, but there's a hint: you can find the position of line break like this: `=SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of functions `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` and `SEARCH()`

To get **part I**:

[image]

To get **part II**:
[image]

Note: I have used `SEARCH` to locate the second instance of a colon ":" and extract the string text after this.

Comment: Thanks. But 1st point is how to convert multi line data (in single cell) to single line data (in multiple cell)?

Comment: You put "on the basis of new line and then detect the first 22 characters" which is part I.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you about this issue. First I want to explain what I understood from your question:

You have a cell containing 2 line string in it like below:

[image]

And you want to split this data into in 2 rows and 2 cells which will contain spesific data as below:

[image]

If I this is what you mean then you can achieve your result if you follow below steps.

1. Since you want to split 1 row into 2 rows you need an empty row below the original one like below:

[image]

2. Then to the cell next to the original cell (in my case it is "B1") enter below formula. Which will give you the first 21 characters of the original cell:

   `=LEFT(A1,21)`

[image]

3. Then to the next cell add the code below to get the "loren ipsum"

   `=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1,1)+1)+1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1,1)-FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1,1)+1)-1)`

[image]

4. Then we move to second row. to the cell "B2" add the code below. Here `CHAR(10)` is the code for new line in the cell:

   `=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1,1),22)`

[image]

5. Finally add the code the the next cell:

   `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","|", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","")))))`

[image]

6. As a result you are going to have something like this:

[image]

I hope this helps.